# how to display grade?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm Trying to write a program to enter a students grade. Their mark should be  between 0 and 100. The program should display:

```
a. "note is A" when the score is 90 and more
b. "note is B" when the note is of 80 or more but less than 90
c. "note is C" when the score is 70 or more but less than 80
d. "note is D" when the score is 60 or more but less than 70
e. 'Failure' when the score is less than 60
f. If the input value is less than 0 or greater than 100 the program should display "Enter a value between 0 and 100"
```

The program must loop continuously

The problem is when I'm running the code it is asking the user to enter the grade but it does not go through my if-else to check what is going to be the note.

```
private static void note()
{
    int[] test = new int[1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= test.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter test " + i);

        Console.ReadLine();

        if ( i<=90)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("note is A");                
        }

        else if (i <=80 || i > 90 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("note is B");
        }

        else if (i <= 70 || i > 80)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("note is C");
        }

        else if (i <= 60 || i > 70)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("note is D");
        }

        else if (i >60)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure");
        }

        else if (i > 0 || i < 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value between 0 and 100");
        }
        else if (i == 999)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you Enterd 999 to stop ");
        }
        test[i] = Console.Read();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see exactly what path it's taking through the code and why?  Look at the debugger windows like "autos" and "locals" to see what the variables are which will help you explain what's going on.

Comment: Why would `i <= 90` be an A?  shouldn't it be `i >= 90`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you made you're code now, it's a wonder if it gives an answer at all.
You should make it like this:

```
private static void note()
{
    int[] i = new int[1];

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter test result");

        i[0]= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        if ( i[0]>=90)
        { 
           Console.WriteLine("note is A");
        }

        else if (i[0] >=80 && i[0] < 90 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("note is B");
        }

        else if (i[0] >= 70 && i[0] < 80)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("note is C");
        }

        else if (i[0] >= 60 && i[0] < 70)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("note is D");
        }

        else if (i[0] < 60)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure");
        }

        else if (i[0] < 0 || i[0] > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value between 0 and 100");
        }
        else if (i[0] == 999)
        { Console.WriteLine("You enterd 999 to stop ");

        }
        Console.Writeline("You're result is:" + i[0]);
   Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

An array of 1 is not very useful. Just make it an int.
And make sure to learn the difference between <, >, >=, <= and between ||, &&

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and Answering m y Question but i have to use an array .

Comment: I'll change it to an array. It's still not very useful to use an array of only 1 item.

Comment: Good answer, this'll produce the correct output. The only thing I'd add is if the OP wants this to be an infinite loop I'd put this whole thing in a do...while(true) loop. I'd also consider using int.TryParse instead of Convert.ToInt32 so that it can handle cases where the user entered something other than an int gracefully.

Comment: You can also probably drop the second condition - e.g. replace "i[0] >=80 && i[0] < 90" with "i[0] >=80" because you already know that i[0] is less than 90 (otherwise the previous condition would've run.

Comment: `i[0]= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` - and app crash if user inputs somthing else than digits

Comment: Answer is correct but you also have unnecessary code.  For example, on line , "else if (i[0] >=80 && i[0] < 90 )" could simply be written "else if (i[0] >=80)", since i[0]>=90 would have been caught by previous if.

Comment: True, the code isn't perfect but I'm not precious about this piece of code that I wrote in like 2 minutes. Feel free to improve it :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several major problems here.

- Why bother making the `test` variable an array if it's only of length 1? Why not just use an `int` instead?
- As BWA pointed out, you're not doing anything with the user input. You read it but you don't store it anywhere or refer to it again. Rather, you're testing against the current iteration value of `i`.
- It's a little unclear why you're asking for user input three times. Get rid of the two calls for user input at the end of the loop and just have a single call at the beginning.
- A "for" loop isn't the correct way of doing an infinite loop (if that's what you're trying to do). You should use `do...while (true)` instead.
- The "for" loop will *always* run exactly twice.
- Your "if" statements are backwards. For example, you assign an "A" if the user got *less than* (or equal to) 90. It should actually be `input >= 90`. Actually, this is true of *almost all* of your if statements (the only one that's correct is that an "F" is less than 60). For example, `i <=80 || i > 90` should actually be `input >= 80`. You should have already tested to see if it's greater than or equal to 90, so you don't need to test that condition again (hence the `else if`), but even if you did want to explicitly check this, the correct way to express this is `i >= 80 && i < 90` - right now you're defining a B as "less than 80 or greater than 90" - in other words, a B is actually being defined as *anything other than* a B.
- You never test to see if the user actually entered an "int." For example, the code was perfectly OK with me entering "a" as an input. In fact, it automatically cast that to its ASCII value, so it looks like the individual got a 97%.
- Entering "999" doesn't actually close the program

For the operators, keep in mind the following:

- && is "and" - e.g. `score >= 80 && score < 90` is "score is at least 80 and less than 90."
- || is "or"
- <= is "less than or equal to"
- > = is "greater than or equal to"

Here's my variant on the above code:

```
 private static void note()
    {
        int[] i = new int[1];
        // Make sure this is an infinite loop
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter test result");

            bool result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i[0]);
            if (!result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
                continue;
            }

            // Test for this and the next conditions first - this'll allow us to shorten the other "if" statements
            if (i[0] == 999)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered 999 to stop");
                // End the loop
                break;
            }
            // The only valid answer that's > 100 is 999
            else if (i[0] < 0 || i[0] > 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a value between 0 and 100");
            }
            // We can't run this condition first because if we did "5000" would "count" as an A (rather than an invalid condition)
            else if (i[0] >= 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is A");
            }
            // No need to explicitly check to see if this is < 90, we know it must be
            // by virtue of the fact that the previous condition is false
            else if (i[0] >= 80)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is B");
            }

            else if (i[0] >= 70)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is C");
            }

            else if (i[0] >= 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("note is D");
            }

            else if (i[0] < 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure");
            }

             Console.WriteLine("Your result is:" + i[0]);
        } while (true);
    }
```

Comment: i really like the way u did it  but there is one problem with it . when it asks the users to enter a grade after displaying the grade it should stops but you are program keep asking users to enter another  input

Comment: You can take the loop out to change that.

Answer (score 2):

You read from console but you do nothing with user input:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

And you check in ifs loop value instead user input.

```
if ( i<=90)
```

You need store somewhere user input:
eg:

```
strig userInmput = Console.ReadLine();
```

And convert it to `int` from `string`
eg:

```
int mark = 0;
bool succes = int.TryParse(userInput, out mark);
if(!succes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Only digits");
}
```

And compare `mark` instead `i`.

Comment: Sorry i did not get you can you explain it a bit more

Comment: @Shahzada You read the user input but you don't store it anywhere or refer to it again.

Answer (score 1):

Put the line `test[i] = Console.Read();` before your checks. You don't put anything to your array. And then check in `if` condition check your array value not your counter (`i`):

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= test.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter test " + i);

        test[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //putting your value

        if (test[i]<=90)//check your value
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("note is A");
        }

        //... same here

       Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: You'll need to parse the result of `Console.ReadLine` into an `int` to be able to put it into `test` array.

Comment: @juharr my bad.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` - and app crash if user inputs somthing else than digit